# Не выводятся данные с сессии

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

```
<?PHP 
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
//error_reporting( E_ERROR );
//require 'db.php';
require 'connection.php';
$data = $_POST;
if (isset($data['do_login']))
{
    $name = $data['name']; //берём имя игрока
    $password = $data['password']; //берём то что пользователь ввёл при авторизации

    $query = "SELECT password FROM accounts WHERE name = '".$name."'"; // запрос в бд
    $user = "SELECT id, name, mail, sex, model, last_ip, password, cash, bank, FROM accounts WHERE name = '".$name."'";
    $bd = mysqli_connect("localhost", "admin", "max777", "database");
    $cache1 = mysqli_query($bd, $user); // Данные для UCP
    $result1 = mysqli_fetch_row($cache1); // Данные для UCP
    $cache = mysqli_query($bd, $query);
    $users[] = $result1[0]; // ID
    $users[] = $result1[1]; // Name
    $users[] = $result1[2]; // Mail
    $users[] = $result1[3]; // Sex
    $users[] = $result1[4]; // Model
    $users[] = $result1[5]; // last_ip
    $users[] = $result1[6]; // password
    $users[] = $result1[7]; // cash
    $users[] = $result1[8]; // bank
    if (mysqli_num_rows($cache)) {
        $result = mysqli_fetch_row($cache);
        $expected_password = $result[0]; // берём пароль из бд
        $hash = hash('md5', $password); // Хэшируем введёный пароль при помощи md5
        if($hash === $expected_password)
        { // если хеш введённого пароля совпадает с хешом из бд значит пароль введён правильно
            $_SESSION['logged_user'] = $users;
            header("Location: panel.php");
        }else
        { // в инном случае введённый пароль не правильный
           ?><script type="text/javascript">alert("Введён неверный логин или пароль!")</script> <?PHP   ;
        }
    } else {
        ?><script type="text/javascript">alert("Введён неверный логин или пароль!")</script> <?PHP  ;
    }

}
?>
```

---

`<?php print_r($_SESSION['logged_user'][1]); ?>` Вот так вот я в ЛК вывожу Имя персонажа, но почему то не выводиться

Comment: Разрабатываю ЛК для сервера ГТА. Есть база данных в который есть аккаунты. Я запросом получаю данные и передаю их в сессию (Сессия стартует в connection.php). Почему то не передаются данные из БД в Сессию а из Сессии соответственно и в ЛК.

Answer (score 0):

Перед тем как записывать данные в сессию или брать их оттуда, сессию надо открывать с помощью функции session_start(). Так же можете попробовать передать идентификатор сессии руками 
Если проблема не устраниться можете поискать решение проблемы здесь: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.session-start.php
http://phpfaq.ru/sessions#bugs

Запись:

```
if($hash === $expected_password)
        { // если хеш введённого пароля совпадает с хешом из бд значит пароль введён правильно
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['logged_user'] = $users;
            header("Location: panel.php?".session_name()."=".session_id());
        }
```

Вывод:

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    print_r($_SESSION['logged_user'][1]); 
?>
```

Comment: Сессия стартуется в файле connection.php и так же он подключается к ЛК. Сессия в ЛК существует, я проверял, но данные почему то не передаются

Comment: В таком случае попробуйте передать идентификатор сессии в header ручками, возможно проблема устранится. Я исправил код в ответе

Comment: Мдааа. Теперь вообще в ЛК не перенаправляет. Что добавил ваш код, что убрал его

Comment: Убрали мой код и все равно не перенаправляет? А вы точно все правильно убрали? ну или хотя бы ошибки можете указать? ответы сервера? Попробуйте после header поставить exit или die для того, что бы программа точно прекратила выполнение. А насчет сессий попробуйте посмотреть на http://phpfaq.ru/sessions#bugs , мне в свое время эта статься помогла избавиться от многих багов связанных с сессиями.